# Problem with MFMailComposeViewController - User Can't Edit Mail Body - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I usually use the below code to allow the user to submit feedback on my apps. However for some reason in my OpenGL app the below code has a problem. It opens the email form correctly, however the form is locked - i.e the user can't actually edit the body of the text. Can anybody spot why this is happening ?

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            picker.mailComposeDelegate = self; 

            [picker setSubject:@"Feedback on Stop That Bomb Free !"];
            NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"anemail@gmail.com"]; 

            [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

            // Fill out the email body text
            NSString *emailBody =
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi Martin, I would like to make the following comment : "];

            [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES]; 

            picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack; 

            [inputController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
            [picker release];
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't figure it out. What did you do to fix?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From reading your code I can find some things you should change:

Replace:

```
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi Martin, I would like to make the following comment : "];
```

With:

```
NSString *emailBody = @"Hi Martin, I would like to make the following comment : ";
```

As you are not using any formatting; you dont need to call the class method to create the simple string.

The other thing you can change is the fact that you message does not contain HTML.

So you dont need `isHTML:YES`.

I have tested this successfully on a sample app.

I imagine the problem is with the view controller presenting the view, rather than the messageUI view.

Comment: This doesn't at all answer the question. What possible problems could there be with the presenting view controller?